# How can I inspect element on a Chromebook when inspection is disabled?

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

I am on a Chromebook controlled by an administration that has disabled the usual Chrome inspection. I am also not allowed to take it out of this administrative lock.

Is there a website available that would allow me to inspect element as a part of that website?

Is there some other way for me to be able to access the console log of a page?

I just need to do some debugging of a program, but I can't find out how to tell if there's an error or not since I can't access the console of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no site or other method available. Usually business and school administration offices disable this on a Chromebook because they give the device to you to use for work, therefore disabling access to certain websites and features. They don't want you to mess around with their devices.

There are 3 solutions to this;

1. Buy a personal Chromebook.
2. Confront the administrator about enabling this feature.
3. Use any Windows or Mac computer, because they allow Inspect Element on desktops for certain reasons.

I hoped this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of schools that provide chromebooks or iPads like to put restrictions on them which include:

- blocking websites
- not allowing certain device features (like playing the dinosaur game when you don't have wifi, inspecting, viewing the source of a webpage, bookmarklets, google assistant, etc.)
- and more

I know this from experience, as I am literally answering your question on a school Chromebook, since Stack Overflow is luckily not blocked.

### There are some ways to fix this.

Reach out to the help desk or IT person at your school/district. Ask them to allow inspecting web pages on your Chromebook. However, you must have a legitimate reason for wanting the Inspect feature, like not because its fun how you can edit a website or whatever, but a reason similar to your reason.

> I just need to do some debugging of a program, but I can't find out how to tell if there's an error or not since I can't access the console of the page.

I'm pretty sure that the help desk/IT at your school will allow you to have the inspect feature because you have a pretty good reason.

Other ways to inspect the website that you wanna inspect are:

- Inspecting the website on a personal Chromebook, Mac, Windows, or other type of computer. Restrictions cannot be put on Macs or Windows computers for inspect, so if a school gave out windows computers, the students could use inspect.